# Let $I=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^n \mid n \in \Bbb N, \forall i \le n :a_i \in R , a_0=0\right\}$. Show that $I$ is an ideal of $R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $I=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^n \mid n \in \Bbb N, \forall i \le n :a_i \in R  , a_0=0\right\}$. Show that $I$ is an ideal of $R[x]$ where $R$ is an arbitary ring.

Let $P,Q \in I$, then $P=a_1x^n + a_2x^n + \dots +a_nx^n$ and $Q=b_1x^n +b_2x^n + \dots +b_nx^n$ and so $$P-Q=(a_1-b_1)x^n + (a_2-b_2)x^n + \dots +(a_n-b_n)x^n \in I$$

Suppose that $f \in R[x]$ and $g \in I$, then $f=a_mx^m + a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \dots + a_0$ and $g=b_nx^n + b_{n-1}x^n + \dots + b_1x^n$. How can I show that $fg =(a_mx^m + a_{m-1}x^{m-1} + \dots + a_0)(b_nx^n + b_{n-1}x^n + \dots + b_1x^n) \in I$?

This kind of multiplication is slightly tedious to compute.

Comment: kernel of evaluation homomorphism

Comment: What is tedious about it? You don't need to compute the whole product, you just need to show that its free term is equal to $0$. That's really not difficult to see. But first write $g$ correctly, you wrote $x^n$ everywhere.